# Angularjs with css3 animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-routing

I have the following code

```
<a href="#local-container" >X</a>
```

So on clicking this link the url changes to

```
http://localhost:8088/#/local-container
```

in angularjs, the problem with this is that I have to capture the active element on click from my css to animate a dom element in the following code,

```
#local-container:target{
left:0px;
width:10px;
}
```

And obviously it won't work because the hashtag is not the same as the div id in the above css.

So is there another way to acheive the animation?
Or do I have to change the url pattern in the angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like `$anchorScroll()`.

[Here is the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24anchorScroll)

Comment: The url changed to `http://localhost:8088/##local-container`, I want `http://localhost:8088/#local-container` there is an extra hash.

Comment: If you really want to keep '#' in the href, you might want to do this: `$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    var old = $location.hash();
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
    //reset to old to keep any additional routing logic from kicking in
    $location.hash(old);
};`

Comment: I am sorry @adam but I feel your answer is out of context. With css I am animating the div.